# Python CGI -------- Multiple Windows & Multiple Downloads

Tags: python, html, download, window, cgi

Well, new to CGI.

Can anyone teach me how to use Python CGI to open severl windows (or tabs) on clicking once on a "submit" button?

And....

How can I provide multiple downloads, which means -- when several files are checked in a checkbox form, and "submit" is clicked -- all the files will be downloaded

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might be more of an html question?

Comment: This is way to broad and vague a question; please do review the [FAQ#dontask]. You cannot, from one HTTP response, open multiple tabs and downloads. You'd have to use client-side scripting (JavaScript) to do so. To explain all that rapidly approaches a full book.

Comment: Sounds like I have raised up a complex question. Thank you all. I will have a look on those solutions later. (smile bitter)

Comment: @Rohan I tried to change header ("Content-Type"), but...

Comment: Look at my edit. I changed it so you only have to click one button.

Comment: Thank you. It does Worked! Though I actually know nothing about javascript... @Tommy3244

Comment: If it worked, could you please press the check to mark it as a best answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a knowledge of HTML and that you use a form in this answer:

Well, I suggest you create a couple of buttons that have links to the URL of the file on the server. The following will work for direct links to the files, but NOT for mirror downloads. It will, though, probably work for a script with the content type values changed to simulate a file.

```
<button value="Download Item 1" onclick="window.open('This is the url of the item to download', '_parent');" />
<button value="Download Item 2" onclick="window.open('This is the url of the item to download', '_parent');" />
<button value="Download Item 3" onclick="window.open('This is the url of the item to download', '_parent');" />
<button value="Download Item 4" onclick="window.open('This is the url of the item to download', '_parent');" />
```

I tried that and it worked for me. Put this in the HTML of the script, not the python code.

EDIT:
For what you want, add the following in the  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download_all()
{
    if(document.getElementById("checkbox1id").checked)
    {
        window.open("URL1", "_parent");
    }
    ect...
}
```

For the checkboxes, you would define each one as so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1id" />
```

And the submit button as so:

```
<button onclick="download_all();" value="Download" />
```

Comment: @ Tommy3244 Thank you. But i really want to use one button for all files

Comment: @ Tommy3244  else those who'd like to download all files may...